# Example of a distribution that is ergodic but not $\phi$-mixing?

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory, time-series, mixing-variables

The book "asymptotic theory for econometricians" ststes the theory that if a stationary sequence is alpha or phi mixing, it is also ergodic, but not the other way around. However, when I look at the definitions they seem intuititely to me to capture the same idea.

**I cannot think of an example of a probability distribution over a stationary time series of random variables that is ergodic but not alpha or phi mixing.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most classical example is the linear process 
$$
X_n:=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} 2^{-i}\xi_{n-i},              
$$
where $\left(\xi_j\right)_{j\in\mathbb Z}    $  is an i.i.d. sequence where $\xi_0$  takes the values $0$ and $1$ with probability $1/2$. Ergodicity follows from the fact that $X_n$ is a functional of i.i.d. and the sequence $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is not mixing  because for all $n$,
$$\left\{X_n\geqslant 2^{-n} \right\}=\left\{\xi_0=1 \right\}$$
up to a set of measure $0$.

Comment: Are you sure about the last equation? If n equals 3 for example, then $\zeta_0$ is multiplied by 1 over 8.